# Search same column with 2 values MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select

I'm not sure how to word what I need so here goes... This is part of a search that allows a type and a state to be selected. I need to be able to run this query to match the type and state from the same mysql column which is meta_value. The problem is it's returning every type for the selected state in the result.

Example: I pick Drag Strip for the type and South Carolina for the state I only want to see the Drag Strip's in South Carolina and not the other types (oval, road course, etc) that are in South Carolina or any other state.

Below is what I have right now that isn't working, I'm not really sure where to go with it to get the result I need.

```
SELECT dmp_postmeta.meta_value, dmp_posts.post_title, dmp_posts.post_type,
       dmp_posts.post_status, dmp_posts.id 
FROM dmp_postmeta, dmp_posts
WHERE dmp_postmeta.meta_value IN ('South Carolina','Drag Strip') 
  AND dmp_posts.post_type='my_custom_tracks' 
  AND dmp_posts.post_status='publish' 
GROUP BY dmp_postmeta.post_id ORDER BY dmp_posts.post_title


meta_key          meta_value
Track_Type        Drag Strip
Track_Type        Oval
Track_Location    South Carolina
Track_Location    Texas
```

******Solved******

```
"SELECT p.ID as id, p.post_title, p.post_type, p.post_status as post_status, MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_value='".$track_type."' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as track_type, MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_value='".$track_state."' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as track_state FROM dmp_posts p LEFT JOIN dmp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID) WHERE p.post_type='my_custom_tracks' AND p.post_status='publish' GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title ORDER BY p.post_title"
```

Comment: What do you mean "type and state from the same column"?  How is one column holding two pieces of information?  Maybe you could provide some examples of what the data looks like in the `meta_value` column.

Comment: I updated the question with what the data looks like. It's the WordPress postmeta table.

Comment: looks like you need an extra condition to join dmp_postdata with dmp_posts

Comment: I went back to the drawing board and approached from a different direction. It does exactly what I need now. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally got to work. Thanks for the help guys.

```
"SELECT p.ID as id, p.post_title, p.post_type, p.post_status as post_status, MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_value='".$track_type."' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as track_type, MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_value='".$track_state."' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as track_state FROM dmp_posts p LEFT JOIN dmp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID) WHERE p.post_type='my_custom_tracks' AND p.post_status='publish' GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title ORDER BY p.post_title"
```